# Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media

Tags: mount

When I try to access my hard disk on Windows I got the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/debo/2290657790655279: Command-line `mount -t
"ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" 
"/dev/sda2" "/media/debo/2290657790655279"' exited with non-zero exit status 14:
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Please can anyone help me on this?

Comment: "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount."  Unless Windows was completely shut down it's in a "saved" state and can't be mounted safely so it refuses to mount.  Boot to windows and initiate the shutdown command, or the reboot command, rather than hibernating Windows.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is exactly what it says. If your windows has not properly shutdown, Ubuntu would not mount it in read write mode as writing to the disk may corrupt it.
You can however mount it in read only mode using the command:

```
mount -o ro /dev/sda2 /media/debo/2290657790655279
```

assuming you want to mount it at /media/debo/2290657790655279, otherwise you can use any other empty directory as a mount point. e.g. to mount in "newfolder" in your home directory:

```
mount -o ro /dev/sda2 ~/newfolder
```

Comment: RO MODE MOUNT WORKS WELL....!!